# Перевести с JavaScript на jQuery

Tags: jquery, javascript

```
    <!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/strict.dtd">
<html>
  <head>
    <meta content="text/html; charset=utf-8" http-equiv="Content-Type">
    <title>new</title>
    <style type="text/css">
        body {}
        #menu { 
                width: 50px; 
                height: 50px; 
                background: red;
                position: absolute;
                top: 100px;
                left: 200px;
        }
        .content {
          height: 2000px;
          background: #FFA0FF;
        }
    </style>

</head>
<body>
        <div id="menu"></div>  
        <div class="content"></div>

        <script type="text/javascript">

        var menu = document.getElementById('menu');
        window.onscroll = function(){
                var scroll = document.documentElement.scrollTop || document.body.scrollTop;
                if(scroll >= 100){
                        menu.style.top = scroll + 'px';
                }else {
                        menu.style.top = 100 + 'px';
                }       
        }
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Вот есть такой код на javascript. Помогите перевести его в jQuery.

Comment: А что вы уже пробовали сделать?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
var $menu = $('#menu');
var scroll; 
var trigger = false;
$(window).scroll(function () { 
     scroll = $(this).scrollTop();    
     if(scroll >= 100){
         if(!trigger){
             trigger = true;
             $menu.css('top', scroll + 'px');
         }
     }
     else if(trigger){
         $menu.css('top', 100 + 'px');
         trigger = false;
     }
});
```

- **[.scroll()](http://api.jquery.com/scroll/)**
- **[.scrollTop()](http://api.jquery.com/scrollTop/)**

**UPD:** немного оптимизировал код